# Table goes to another page. It has some residual lines

Tags: tables, alignment

here is the code. As you see there are several problems with this table. I really don't know how to make those lines disappear and bring the whole table to the first page.
Thanks!
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Maze Score Sheet} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 1 &  & 26 &  & 51 &  & 76 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 2 &  & 27 &  & 52 &  & 77 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 3 &  & 28 &  & 53 &  & 78 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 4 &  & 29 &  & 54 &  & 79 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 5 &  & 30 &  & 55 &  & 80 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 6 &  & 31 &  & 56 &  & 81 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 7 &  & 32 &  & 57 &  & 82 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 8 &  & 33 &  & 58 &  & 83 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 9 &  & 34 &  & 59 &  & 84 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 10 & & 35 &  & 60 &  & 85 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 11 & & 36 &  & 61 &  & 86 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 12 & & 37 &  & 62 &  & 87 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 13 & & 38 &  & 63 &  & 88 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 14 & & 39 &  & 64 &  & 89 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 15 & & 40 &  & 65 &  & 90 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 16 & & 41 &  & 66 &  & 91 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 17 & & 42 &  & 67 &  & 92 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 18 & & 43 &  & 68 &  & 93 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 19 & & 44 &  & 69 &  & 94 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 20 & & 45 &  & 70 &  & 95 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 21 & & 46 &  & 71 &  & 96 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 22 & & 47 &  & 72 &  & 97 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 23 & & 48 &  & 73 &  & 98 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 24 & & 49 &  & 74 &  & 99 & \\
\rule{0pt}{20pt} 25 & & 50 &  & 75 &  & 100 &\\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! your table is to tall for available text height. you have two possibilities: (i) increase text height (for this page) , or (ii) reduce cells height (for about 3.5 pt).

Comment: Which residual lines? I see the page layout markers by `showframe=true` option of `geometry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let mi elaborate my comment. your table is moving to the next page because it is to height. lines which you see on the first page (they are also on the second, but they are less visible since they are covered by table) show page layout and are generated by `geometry` option `showframe`, are not the cause that table is not on the first page (where you expected to be). considering my second suggestion in comment -- reduce table height -- gives:

[image]

assuming, that all columns in table have the same width, i suggest to use `tabularx` table environment. for more vertical space in table body i would rather use `cellspace` package then `\rule{0pt}{20pt}`. to have different heights of columns' headers i enclosed them in `multicolumn` macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[%showframe          % show page layout
                                % handy in phase of table design
                                % in real document had to be removed
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace,          % for defining vertical space above and bottom of cells' content
            tabularx}           % for `X` column type
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}       % additional top vertical space
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}    % additional bottom vertical space
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    % for center content in X colums
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}          % shorthand for multicolum

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begingroup
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5pt}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{8}{SC|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Maze Score Sheet} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!40}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Trial}   & \mc{Score}
    & \mc{Trial} & \mc{Score}
    & \mc{Trial} & \mc{Score} & \mc{Trial} & \mc{Score} \\
\hline
1 &  & 26 &  & 51 &  & 76 & \\
2 &  & 27 &  & 52 &  & 77 & \\
3 &  & 28 &  & 53 &  & 78 & \\
4 &  & 29 &  & 54 &  & 79 & \\
5 &  & 30 &  & 55 &  & 80 & \\
6 &  & 31 &  & 56 &  & 81 & \\
7 &  & 32 &  & 57 &  & 82 & \\
8 &  & 33 &  & 58 &  & 83 & \\
9 &  & 34 &  & 59 &  & 84 & \\
10 & & 35 &  & 60 &  & 85 & \\
11 & & 36 &  & 61 &  & 86 & \\
12 & & 37 &  & 62 &  & 87 & \\
13 & & 38 &  & 63 &  & 88 & \\
14 & & 39 &  & 64 &  & 89 & \\
15 & & 40 &  & 65 &  & 90 & \\
16 & & 41 &  & 66 &  & 91 & \\
17 & & 42 &  & 67 &  & 92 & \\
18 & & 43 &  & 68 &  & 93 & \\
19 & & 44 &  & 69 &  & 94 & \\
20 & & 45 &  & 70 &  & 95 & \\
21 & & 46 &  & 71 &  & 96 & \\
22 & & 47 &  & 72 &  & 97 & \\
23 & & 48 &  & 73 &  & 98 & \\
24 & & 49 &  & 74 &  & 99 & \\
25 & & 50 &  & 75 &  & 100 &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
```

Comment: @MohDasti, you are welcome. temporary your reputation is to low for voting answer (and by this say "thank you"), but you can select one from received answers which you most like and accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answers) :-). happy tex-ing!

Answer (score 1):

To make the framelines disappear, don't specify the option `showframe` when loading the `geometry` package.

I take it that the objective is to make the scoresheet fill up the available text block. If that's the case, don't overuse `adjustbox`, and don't use `\rule{0pt}{20pt}` to insert typographic struts in every single row. Setting `\tabcolsep` and `\arraystretch` to reasonable values is much more effective.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] % place the table on a page by itself
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm} % this is really ugly...
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{14.1pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\noindent % <--- this is important
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Maze Score Sheet} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!40}
Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score \\
\hline
1 &  & 26 &  & 51 &  & 76 & \\
2 &  & 27 &  & 52 &  & 77 & \\
3 &  & 28 &  & 53 &  & 78 & \\
4 &  & 29 &  & 54 &  & 79 & \\
5 &  & 30 &  & 55 &  & 80 & \\
6 &  & 31 &  & 56 &  & 81 & \\
7 &  & 32 &  & 57 &  & 82 & \\
8 &  & 33 &  & 58 &  & 83 & \\
9 &  & 34 &  & 59 &  & 84 & \\
10 & & 35 &  & 60 &  & 85 & \\
11 & & 36 &  & 61 &  & 86 & \\
12 & & 37 &  & 62 &  & 87 & \\
13 & & 38 &  & 63 &  & 88 & \\
14 & & 39 &  & 64 &  & 89 & \\
15 & & 40 &  & 65 &  & 90 & \\
16 & & 41 &  & 66 &  & 91 & \\
17 & & 42 &  & 67 &  & 92 & \\
18 & & 43 &  & 68 &  & 93 & \\
19 & & 44 &  & 69 &  & 94 & \\
20 & & 45 &  & 70 &  & 95 & \\
21 & & 46 &  & 71 &  & 96 & \\
22 & & 47 &  & 72 &  & 97 & \\
23 & & 48 &  & 73 &  & 98 & \\
24 & & 49 &  & 74 &  & 99 & \\
25 & & 50 &  & 75 &  & 100 &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adjusting the width, use `\makebox[\linewidth]{<table>}` to center the table automatically and don't forget `\noindent` also. As others said, use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{<value>}` instead of adding a `\rule` at every row. Finally consider choosing more sensible values for `\arrayrulewidth` and `\tabcolsep` for the most visual clarity.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}  % <---
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}    
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{% <---
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|*8{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Maze Score Sheet} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score & Trial & Score \\
\hline
 1 &  & 26 &  & 51 &  &  76 & \\
 2 &  & 27 &  & 52 &  &  77 & \\
 3 &  & 28 &  & 53 &  &  78 & \\
 4 &  & 29 &  & 54 &  &  79 & \\
 5 &  & 30 &  & 55 &  &  80 & \\
 6 &  & 31 &  & 56 &  &  81 & \\
 7 &  & 32 &  & 57 &  &  82 & \\
 8 &  & 33 &  & 58 &  &  83 & \\
 9 &  & 34 &  & 59 &  &  84 & \\
10 &  & 35 &  & 60 &  &  85 & \\
11 &  & 36 &  & 61 &  &  86 & \\
12 &  & 37 &  & 62 &  &  87 & \\
13 &  & 38 &  & 63 &  &  88 & \\
14 &  & 39 &  & 64 &  &  89 & \\
15 &  & 40 &  & 65 &  &  90 & \\
16 &  & 41 &  & 66 &  &  91 & \\
17 &  & 42 &  & 67 &  &  92 & \\
18 &  & 43 &  & 68 &  &  93 & \\
19 &  & 44 &  & 69 &  &  94 & \\
20 &  & 45 &  & 70 &  &  95 & \\
21 &  & 46 &  & 71 &  &  96 & \\
22 &  & 47 &  & 72 &  &  97 & \\
23 &  & 48 &  & 73 &  &  98 & \\
24 &  & 49 &  & 74 &  &  99 & \\
25 &  & 50 &  & 75 &  & 100 &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]